# Can’t get the EON chart to populate after changing from ‘demo’ keys to my keys

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I'm using a simple demo tutorial using the ‘demo’ keys and it working fine. As soon as I change the ‘publish_key’ and ‘subscription_key’ to my own keys (from PubNub), it doesn't work anymore. Looking at the PubNub debug monitor, I see the app publishing fine, but the chart doesn’t receive anything from the subscription. I guess I’m missing something fundamental here. Can anyone help me on the right track?

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pubnub.github.io/eon/lib/eon.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://pubnub.github.io/eon/lib/eon.css" />

<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
    var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
        publish_key: 'pub-c-be6f6fd9-ebd3-496b-9490-50e82e5a2f01',
        subscribe_key: 'sub-c-08b50a70-3c9e-11e6-9baf-0619f8945a4f'
    });

    eon.chart({
        channel: 'eon-bar-chart',
        generate: {
            bindto: '#chart',
            data: {
                type: 'bar'
            }
        }
    });

    setInterval(function() {

        pubnub.publish({
            channel: 'eon-bar-chart',
            message: {
                columns: [
                    ['Austin', Math.floor(Math.random() * 99)],
                    ['New York', Math.floor(Math.random() * 99)],
                    ['San Francisco', Math.floor(Math.random() * 99)],
                    ['Portland', Math.floor(Math.random() * 99)]
                ]
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Declaring & Init'ing `pubnub` variable in PubNub EON

[Some of the PubNub EON examples do not show explicit declaration/initialization](https://github.com/pubnub/eon-chart#simple-example) of the `pubnub` variable but there is no use case where you should not do this.

You need to [add the `pubnub` key/value to the `eon.chart` object](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/chart/gauge/):

```
eon.chart({
        pubnub: pubnub,
        channel: 'eon-bar-chart',
        generate: {
            bindto: '#chart',
            data: {
                type: 'bar'
            }
        }
});
```

Without that key/value, PubNub tries to use demo keys by default.

Comment: That’s it! I did not see that. Now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: The docs need to be updated to show this explicit declaration in all samples because the default demo keys is no longer supported in the current PubNub JavaScript SDK.

Comment: I updated the readme's in EON github repo's to show usage of pubnub var.